# Beamer option breaks align-in-tabular

Tags: tables, beamer, align

I'm trying to put an align environment inside of a tabular environment. Here is a snippet:

```
%\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.8\textwidth}}
\begin{align*}
x^{2}+2x+1 = 0
\end{align*}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

As written, the document compiles just fine. With the commented `documentclass` (setting `xcolor=table`), I get the following error:

`! Misplaced \omit.
\math@cr@@@ ...@ \@ne \add@amps \maxfields@ \omit 
                                                  \kern -\alignsep@ \iftag@ ...
l.10 \end{align*}`

Why?

Comment: Replace `\begin{align*}` with `\[ \begin{aligned}` and `\end{align*}` with `\end{aligned} \]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replacing `\begin{align*}` with `\[ \begin{aligned}` and `\end{align*}` with `\end{aligned} \]` lets you compile the test file.

That said, it's not at all clear why you'd wish to employ an `align*` environment to begin with, since no alignment of any kind is being performed.

Comment: I was just reducing the complexity of the example for the MWE (since the crash still occurred on the test code). This solution appears to work, thank you!